# TreeMap doesn't work for some of keys

Tags: java, dictionary, treemap

I'm implementing a `TreeMap` in java today to track the navigation for next page.
I have 5 entries in the treemap, 3 of them works while 2 don't work.

NavigationHelper.java :

```
public class NavigationHelper {

private static String hhSection = HXConstants.CSR_SECTION_FAMILY_DETAILS;
private static String[] hhPages = {
        HXConstants.CSR_PAGE_ID_HOUSEHOLD_MEMBERS, 
            HXConstants.CSR_PAGE_ID_HOUSEHOLD_RELATIONSHIP, 
                HXConstants.CSR_PAGE_ID_HOUSEHOLD_ADDITIONAL_QUESTIONS,
                    HXConstants.CSR_PAGE_ID_HOUSEHOLD_SUMMARY_NEW,
                        HXConstants.CSR_PAGE_ID_HOUSEHOLD_PRIVACY_AGREEMENT
};
private static String hhPath = "household";
public static HashMap<String, NavLocation> getHHNavMap()
{

    HashMap<String, NavLocation> hhNavMap = new HashMap<String, NavLocation>();
    for (int i=0;i<hhPages.length;i++ ) {
        hhNavMap.put(hhPath+"/"+hhPages[i], new NavLocation(hhSection,hhPages[i]));
    }
    return hhNavMap;
}

public static Map<NavLocation,String> getHHBackNavMap() {
    TreeMap<NavLocation,String> hhBackNavMap = new TreeMap<NavLocation, String>();
    HashMap<String, NavLocation> hhNavMap = getHHNavMap();
    for(Entry<String, NavLocation> entry : hhNavMap.entrySet()) {
        hhBackNavMap.put(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
    }
    return hhBackNavMap;
}


public static class NavLocation implements Comparable<NavLocation>{
    private String section;
    public NavLocation(String s, String p) {
        this.section = s;
        this.page = p;
    }
    public String getSection() {
        return section;
    }

    public String getPage() {
        return page;
    }
    private String page;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(NavLocation navObj) {
        if(navObj.getPage().equals(this.page) && (navObj.getSection().equals(this.section)))
            return 0;
        return 1;
    }

}
}
```

AppAggNavigationHelper.java :

```
public class AppAggNavigationHelper extends RestServiceBaseTest {

private static String hhSection = HXConstants.CSR_SECTION_FAMILY_DETAILS;
private static String[] hhPages = {
        HXConstants.CSR_PAGE_ID_HOUSEHOLD_MEMBERS, 
            HXConstants.CSR_PAGE_ID_HOUSEHOLD_RELATIONSHIP, 
                HXConstants.CSR_PAGE_ID_HOUSEHOLD_ADDITIONAL_QUESTIONS,
                    HXConstants.CSR_PAGE_ID_HOUSEHOLD_SUMMARY_NEW,
                        HXConstants.CSR_PAGE_ID_HOUSEHOLD_PRIVACY_AGREEMENT
};

NavigationHelper navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper();
List<NavLocation> navList = new ArrayList<NavLocation>();

@Before
public void populateNavLocations() {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < hhPages.length ; i++) {
        navList.add(new NavLocation(hhSection, hhPages[i]));
    }
}

@Test
public void test() {
    testWithoutRest();
}



public void testWithoutRest() {
    TreeMap<NavLocation,String> map = (TreeMap<NavLocation, String>) navigationHelper.getHHBackNavMap();
    for(Map.Entry<NavLocation, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        NavLocation nav = entry.getKey();
        System.out.println(nav.getPage() + " " + nav.getSection());
        System.out.println(entry.getValue());

    }
    p("*****");
    for(NavLocation navLocation : navList) {
        System.out.println(navLocation.getPage() + " " + navLocation.getSection() + " " + map.get(navLocation));
    }
}
}
```

Then the output is wired, for member, summary, privacy it's working.
But for relation and questions it's not.
:

```
member familydetails household/member

relation familydetails null

question familydetails null

summary familydetails household/summary

privacy familydetails household/privacy
```

Why relation and question are not working?

Comment: your comparable implementation is wrong. google it to learn how to implement it correctly.

Comment: You can't compare by only using *is same* and *is not same*. You need to define an order. An order contains *is same*, *is less* and *is greater*, you miss one of them. By definition if you say `a > b` (the case where you return `1`) you must also say `b < a` (return something negative) for the same arguments in the other order. Also, you return `1` if elements are not equal. This is problematic, take the numbers `5` and `4`, they are not equal and you return `1` which means *is greater*, so `5 > 4`. But you also return `1` for `4` and `5`, which means `4 > 5` which is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `compareTo` method is broken. If two `NavLocation` objects, `a` and `b` differ in their page or section, both `a.compareTo(b)` and `b.compareTo(a)` will return `1`, thus violating the general contract of the method, which may lead to unexpected results.

Instead, the classic way to implement such a method depending on the objects properties would probably look something like this:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(NavLocation other) {
    int result = getPage().compareTo(other.getPage());
    if (result != 0) {
        return result;
    }

    return getSection().compareTo(other.getSection());
}
```